# Stored procedure to count then divide a column

Tags: sql

I don't exactly know how to title this question. But I am looking to create a stored procedure or procedures to create a new table with averages. I have 19 sites that I have collected survey data from. I want to count each column two but with two different conditions. 
E.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(ColumnName)
FROM TableName
WHERE ColumnName = 3

SELECT COUNT(ColumnName)
FROM TableName
WHERE ColumnName = 4
```

From there I would like to add those two numbers together then divide by another count for another column in the table.

Basically I want to know how many surveys have the answer 3 and 4 then divide them by how many surveys were answered. Also keep in mind I want numbers based on each site.

Comment: So I have gotten a bit closer to what I want trying to achieve but it is still not doing what I want it do. This is what I have come up with but I don't know how to get to divide by the sum.                                                              SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Resident_Survey WHERE CanbealonewhenIwish = 3 and Village = 'WP' and Setting = 'LTC')+
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Resident_Survey WHERE CanbealonewhenIwish = 4 and Village = 'WP' and Setting = 'LTC')/ 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Resident_Survey WHERE Village = 'WP' and Setting = 'LTC')
AS ICanbealonewhenIwish

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by`:

```
select columnname
from tablename
where columnname in (3, 4)
group by columname;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seems want :

```
select sum(case when col in (3,4) then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)
from table t
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have gotten a bit closer to what I want trying to achieve but it is still not doing what I want it do. This is what I have come up with but I don't know how to get to divide by the sum. SELECT (SELECT COUNT() FROM Resident_Survey WHERE CanbealonewhenIwish = 3 and Village = 'WP' and Setting = 'LTC')+ (SELECT COUNT() FROM Resident_Survey WHERE CanbealonewhenIwish = 4 and Village = 'WP' and Setting = 'LTC')/ (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Resident_Survey WHERE Village = 'WP' and Setting = 'LTC') AS ICanbealonewhenIwish

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was looking to create this query.
SELECT 100.0 *
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Privacyisrespected IN (3,4)
                THEN 1
                ELSE NULL END) /
    COUNT(*) AS Myprivacyisrespected
FROM Resident_Survey
WHERE Village = 'WP'
    and Setting = 'LTC'